# How do I solve this question about Pigeonhole Principle (Discrete Mathematics)?

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

I am not understanding the following question. I mean I want to know the sample input output for this problem question: "The pigeonhole principle states that if a function f has n distinct inputs but less than n distinct outputs,then there exist two inputs a and b such that a!=b and f(a)=f(b). Present an algorithm to find a and b such that f(a)=f(b). Assume that the function inputs are 1,2,......,and n.?"

I am unable to solve this problem as I am not understanding the question clearly. looking for your help.

Comment: This site is for programming Q&A. You will have better luck at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Aaron Algorithms are programming/CS, not Math.

Comment: @RBarryYoung The line between discrete math and CS can be blurry, regardless, this question probably belongs http://cs.stackexchange.com/ or http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RBarryYoung algorithms are exclusive to CS at all. They are merely a set of steps to be followed, programmed or otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well let's go step by step.

#### I have 2 boxes. My father gave me 3 chocolates....

And I want to put those chocolates in 2 boxes. For our benefit let's name the chocolate `a`,`b`,`c`.

So how many ways we can put them?

```
[ab][c]
[abc][]
[a][bc]
```

And you see something strange? There is atleast one box with more than 1 chocolate.

So what do you think?

You can try this with any number of boxes and chocolates ( more than number of boxes) and try this. You will see that it's right.

### Well let's make it more easy:

I have 5 friends 3 rooms. We  are having a party. And now let's see what happens. (All my friends will sit in any of the room)

I am claiming that there will be atleast one room where there will be more than 1 friend.

My friends are quite mischievious and knowing this they tried to prove me wrong.

- Friend-1 selects room-1.
- Friend-2 thinks why room-1? Then I will be correct so he selects room-2
- Friend-3 also thinks same...he avoids 1 and 2 room and get into room-3
- Friend-4 now comes and he understands that there is no other empty room and so he has to enter some room. And thus I become correct.

So you understand the situation?

There n friends (funtions) but unfortunately or (fortunately) their rooms (output values) are less than n. So ofcourse one of the there exists 2 friend of mine `a` and `b` who shares the same room.( same value `f(a)=f(b)`)

Comment: hmm i am clear with the theory now thank you,but is there any way to solve it without hashing? given sample input output will also be beneficial.thank you

Comment: @MobassirHossen.: If answer helped you please upvote..Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The pigeonhole principle says that if you have more items than boxes, at least one of the boxes must have multiple items in it.

If you want to find which items a != b have the property f(a) == f(b), a straightforward approach is to use a hashmap data structure.  Use the function value f(x) as key to store the item value x.  Iterate through the items, x=1,...,n.  If there is no entry at f(x), store x.  If there is, the current value of x and the value stored at f(x) are a pair of the type you're seeking.

In pseudocode:

```
h = {}  # initialize an empty hashmap
for x in 1,...,n
    if h[f(x)] is empty
       h[f(x)] <- x   # store x in the hashmap indexed by f(x)
    else
       (x, h[f(x)]) qualify as a match    # do what you want with them
```

If you want to identify *all* pigeons who have roommates, initialize the hashmap with empty sets.  Then iterate through the values and append the current value x to the set indexed by f(x).  Finally, iterate through the hashmap and pick out all sets with more than one element.

---

Since you didn't specify a language, for the fun of it I decided to implement the latter algorithm in Ruby:

```
N = 10  # number of pigeons

# Create an array of value/function pairs.
# Using N-1 for range of rand guarantees at least one duplicate random
# number, and with the nature of randomness, quite likely more.
value_and_f = Array.new(N) { |index| [index, rand(N-1)]}

h = {}  # new hash

puts "Value/function pairs..."
p value_and_f  # print the value/function pairs

value_and_f.each do |x, key|
  h[key] = [] unless h[key]  # create an array if none exists for this key
  h[key] << x                # append the x to the array associated with this key
end

puts "\nConfirm which values share function mapping"
h.keys.each { |key| p h[key] if h[key].length > 1 }
```

Which produces the following output, for example:

```
Value/function pairs...
[[0, 0], [1, 3], [2, 1], [3, 6], [4, 7], [5, 4], [6, 0], [7, 1], [8, 0], [9, 3]]

Confirm which values share function mapping
[0, 6, 8]
[1, 9]
[2, 7]
```

Since this implementation uses randomness, it will produce different results each time you run it.

Comment: i am extremely sorry,i should have specified the language.i work on c.i prefer c code,can you please give me a straightforward algorithm to do it in c? i haven't learnt hashing yet,i wonder if there is any other straightforward easy way to implement this problem in c language,thank you

Comment: You can replace the hash with an array of arrays, since you're using integer values.  However, I'm not going to write it for you.  You asked for an algorithm, I've given you one in pseudocode and demonstrated that it actually works.  You'll have to be the one to translate it to the language you want to work in.

Comment: Stating that you want a C implementation and that you want a solution that avoids hashing changes your question.  That's frowned upon on StackOverflow.  Instead, you should post the more constrained version as a different question.  Be aware, though, you're very likely to get people downvoting you and telling you that SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: thank you for your advice,i am new to stack overflow,i've created the account of stack overflow 4/5 days ago thats why i am not familiar with its lows.ok i will try to solve it on my own.thank you

Answer (score 0):

Continuing what https://stackoverflow.com/a/42254627/7256243 said. 
Lets say that you map an array A of length N to an array B with length N-1.
Than the result could be an array B; were for 1 index you would have 2 elements.

```
A = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
map A -> B
```

Were a possible solution could be.

```
B= {1,2,{3,4},5,6}
```

The mapping of A -> could be done in any number of ways.
Here in this example both input index of 3 and 4 in Array A have the same index in array B.

I hope this usefull.

Comment: sorry dear,are you talking about hashing? what does map a and b means?i haven't learnt hashing yet,i am seeking the solution and sample input output for this problem,i want to implement in c using naive approach,i wish you could help me with this!